# Declaring an extern variable as base and derived class pointers

Tags: c++, c++builder, extern

Say we have a situation like this:

base.h:

```
class Base { };
```

derived.h:

```
#include "base.h"
class Derived : public Base { };
extern Derived *variable;
```

derived.cpp:

```
#include "derived.h"
Derived *variable;
```

Is it correct to declare `variable` as a pointer to `Base` in elsewhere.cpp?

```
class Base;
extern Base *variable;
```

The C++Builder linker doesn't complain and everything seems to work. Is this safe and correct according to the standard, or should every declaration of `variable`be of the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few ways this can go wrong (aside from being undefined behavior, which means that you shouldn't even rely on one of those happening):

- The compiler might make the type part of the mangling of the variable. Apparently C++Builder doesn't, but I'm pretty sure MSVC does. If it does, you get linker errors.
- Suppose at some point `Derived` is changed to

  `class Derived : public Something, public Base {};`

  where `Something` isn't empty, then in most ABIs, a `Derived*` changes its value when it's cast to a `Base*`. However, the aliasing of the global variable bypasses this adjustment, leaving you with a `Base*` that doesn't point to a `Base`.
- The compiler might actually detect your ODR violation through some other means and just error out.
- What happens if you assign an object of type `OtherDerived` (which also derives from `Base`, but not `Derived`) to your `variable`? The parts of the program that see it as a `Derived*` expect it to point to a `Derived`, but it really points to a `OtherDerived`. You can see the most fascinating effects in such code. You could set it up so that calling virtual function `foo` calls the `Derived` version while `foo2` calls the `OtherDerived` version. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 2):

It's not OK. If the name `variable` is supposed to refere to the same entity (which it is, since it's `extern`), then it must have the same type. Otherwise, you'll be violating ODR (One Definition Rule).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's not fine.

It creates an ambiguity in some cases:

```
// Example Function:
void do_stuff(Base* b);

// Code
do_stuff(variable); // You could mean Derived* or Base*.
                    // You would write the same thing, but mean 
                    // 2 different things.
```